# Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7 not working and displaying [/group] in output

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, conditional-content

I'm trying to get [Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7](https://conditional-fields-cf7.bdwm.be/) up and running in WordPress. I'm using Contact Form 7 version 5.1.3 and Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields version 1.9.14.

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://conditional-fields-cf7.bdwm.be/conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7-tutorial/), which gives you the final code to paste into the Contact Form 7 **Form** tab:

```
Your name: [text your-name]
Your email address: [email* your-email]
<p>What kind of support do you want?
[select* support-type first_as_label "-- Choose support type --" "Technical support" "Sales"]</p>
[group technical-support-selected]
  <p>Your operating system: [select* operating-system first_as_label "-- Choose your operating system --" "Android" "iOS" "Linux" "Windows" "Other"]</p>
  [group os-selected]
<p>Please specify your [group os-android inline]Android[/group][group os-iOS inline]iOS[/group][group os-linux inline]Linux[/group][group os-windows inline]Windows[/group] version:
    [text* version]</p>
  [/group]
  [group os-other-selected]
    <p>Please specify your OS and version.
    [text* other-os "Operating System"][text* other-version "Version"]</p>
  [/group]
[/group]
[group sales-support-selected]
  <p>Where is your business located?
  [select* continent first_as_label "-- Choose your continent --" "Europe" "America" "Africa" "Asia" "Oceania" "Antarctica"]</p>
[/group]

<p>[textarea comments]</p>

[submit "Send"]
```

and this code to paste into the **Conditional Fields** tab in **Text** view:

```
show [technical-support-selected] if [support-type] equals "Technical support"
show [sales-support-selected] if [support-type] equals "Sales"
show [os-selected] if [operating-system] not equals ""
               and if [operating-system] not equals "Other"
show [os-android] if [operating-system] equals "Android"
show [os-iOS] if [operating-system] equals "iOS"
show [os-linux] if [operating-system] equals "Linux"
show [os-windows] if [operating-system] equals "Windows"
show [os-other-selected] if [operating-system] equals "Other"
```

However, when I paste the code in, the final output isn't hiding anything and `[/group]` shows through to the output. Here's a screen grab:

[image]

Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: I'd try removing most of the conditional sections and adding them back in one by one to work out which one is causing the problems. I'd guess it's the `<p>Please specify your [group os-android inline]Android[/group]` line as that isn't choosing which device name to display correctly.

Comment: But if you need expertise specific to that plugin you should probably ask the authors directly.

Comment: Thanks, Rup. Given that that code is straight from the author's tutorial, I doubt it's something inherent in the code; more likely something to do with my set-up in some way that's not apparent to me. I did actually reach out to the author after posting this so hopefully he'll be able to reply soon.

Comment: Hopefully! But just because it's from official documentation doesn't mean it definitely works though - the documentation might be out of date, or it might have been broken by a bug since it was written.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following code to your `functions.php` file,

`add_filter( 'wpcf7_autop_or_not','__return_false');`

the will remove the `<p></p>` wrapping tags added by the CF7 plugin for each new line in your form.